# K-means clustering model fitting in android studio with Chaquopy SDK is not working

Tags: android-studio, scikit-learn, model, k-means, chaquopy

I want to generate random K values based on the image. My code is working in python script but while integrating with Chaquopy. When I am debugging my code, the code is not working and not throwing errors also.

```
def Adaptive_K_Value(image):
    
    print(image)
    data = image / 255.0  # use 0...1 scale
    print(data)
    data = data.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3)
    print(data.shape)

    data = np.array(data)
    print(data)
 
    max_Dunn = float("-inf")
    min_DB = float("inf")
    max_Silhoutte = float("-inf")
    max_Calinski = float("-inf")

    ideal_k = k = 2

    while True:
        print("k = ", k + 1)
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
        print("kmeans ",kmeans)
        print(data.shape)
        
        kmeans.fit(data)
        print("fitted model ",kmeans)

        kmeans_labels = kmeans.labels_
        print(kmeans.labels_)
        print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

        distances = pairwise_distances(data)
        Dunn = dunn(distances, kmeans_labels)
        print("Dunn Index kmeans =", Dunn)
        DB = davies_bouldin_score(data, kmeans_labels)
        print("DB Index kmeans =", DB)
        Silhoutte = silhouette_score(data, kmeans_labels)
        print('Silhouette Score kmeans=', Silhoutte)
        Calinski = metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(data, kmeans_labels)
        print('Calinski-Harabasz Index kmeans =', Calinski)

        count = 0
        if max_Dunn < Dunn:
            count += 1
        if min_DB > DB:
            count += 1
        if max_Silhoutte < Silhoutte:
            count += 1
        if max_Calinski < Calinski:
            count += 1
        if count < 2:
            break
        else:
            ideal_k = k
            k += 1
            max_Dunn = Dunn
            min_DB = DB
            max_Silhoutte = Silhoutte
            max_Calinski = Calinski

    print("\nOptimum K value =", ideal_k + 1)
    return ideal_k
```

I am trying to implement Adaptive_K_Value() method to get random K values from the image.
This line **kmeans.fit(data)** is not working. While loop is terminating directly. It just printing **KMeans(n_clusters=3)** means this line ->  **kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)** is only working.
Please help me

Logs of Android Studio
[image]

Here the k-means model is just initialized but the fitting part is not working. When I run the python script on the command line it returns the K value.

Comment: "The code is not working" -- in what way? What is happening, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to give more detail than that. You have some print statements. What's it printing, and what did you expect it to print?

Comment: Wanted to know if Clustering is supported by Chaquopy or not.

Comment: Chaquopy supports the entire scikit-learn API as far as I know, but there may be a difference in behavior depending on the scikit-learn version ([Chaquopy currently supports version 0.24.1](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/scikit-learn/)). I'm not very familiar with scikit-learn, so I'll add that tag to the question to attract more attention. But I doubt anyone will help you unless you explain clearly what it's printing and what you expected it to print.

Comment: I added log details of android studio. Here till kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k), the code is working but when I am trying kmeans.fit(data). My app is crashing without error.